# Meteor: insert document upon newly created user

Tags: meteor

This is probably more simple than I'm making it sound.

I'm allowing my users to create their myprofile when the signin. This is a document that is stored in `MyProfile = new Meteor.Collection('myprofile');`. The principle is exactly the same as LinkedIn...you login, and you fill out a profile form and any edits you make simply updates that one document.

Within the document there will be fields such as 'summary' 'newsInterest' and others, also 'owner' which is the users Id.

**1) How can I insert a document into the MyProfile collection with the 'owner' field being the userId of the newly created user on StartUp?**

This is so that the data of this document, the values of these fields will be passed onto the myprofile page. Initially the values returned will be blank but as the user types, upon keyup the myprofile document will be updated.

Users are created as follows on the client. This is fine for now.

**2) In addition, please provide any links if people have created users on the server. I called a method to insert the following as an object into `Meteor.users.insert(object);`but this does not work.**

```
Template.join.events({
'submit #join-form': function(e,t){
e.preventDefault();
Accounts.createUser({
  username: t.find('#join-username').value,
  password: t.find('#join-password').value,
  email: t.find('#join-email').value,
  profile:{
    fullname: t.find('#join-fullname').value,
summary: [],
newsInterest: [],
otherstuff: []
  }
});
Router.go('myprofile');
}
});
```

Comment: I would recommend adding the Router.go('myprofile') into the createUSer callback so that if for whatever reason createUser errors it won't try to change page and you can show an error to the user. See my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** In order to solve issue one you have two options.

Instead of having a separate collection for profiles like you would in a normalized MySQL database for example. Add the users profile data within the profile object already attached to objects in the user collection. You can then pass in the values you want in the options parameter of the [Accounts.createUser function](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser)

```
Template.join.events({
  "submit #join-form": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $('input#firstName').val(),
    lastName = $('input#lastName').val(),
    username = firstName + '.' + lastName,
    email = $('input#email').val(),
    password = $('input#password').val(),
    profile = {
      name: firstName + ' ' + lastName
    };
    Accounts.createUser({
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      profile: profile
    }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      } else {
        Router.go('myprofile');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This is an example using jQuery to get the values but your t.find should work equally fine.

If you really do want to use a separate collection then I recommend using the following code inside the [onCreateUser function](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) (server side) instead:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user._id = Meteor.users._makeNewID();

    profile = options.profile;
    profile.userId = user._id;

    MyProfile.insert(profile);

    return user;
});
```

When you want to update or add additional data into the profile field for a user you can use the following:

```
var newProfile = {
    summary: 'This summary',
    newsInterest: 'This newsInterest',
    otherstuff: 'Stuff'
};

Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId, {$set: {profile: newProfile}});
```

Or if you went for the separate collection option the following:

```
var newProfile = MyProfile.findOne(Meteor.userId);
newProfile.summary = 'This summary';
newProfile.newsInterest = 'This newsInterest';
newProfile.otherstuff = 'Stuff';

MyProfile.update(Meteor.userId, newProfile);
```

Haven't tested this so let my know if I have any syntax / typo errors and I'll update.

Comment: Hi Will, I think for my purpose, it would be ideal to simple store this profile information within the user instead of a collection. Thanks for pointing out this option. Is the onCreateser code stored on the server? Thank you and richsilv for contributing so far.

By the way in your code for the event, should last name be a variable as well? As, im using the t.find method this part of the code in not necessary for me

Comment: Ye in my projects in normally put it in a /server/accounts.js file.

You can pass any variables you like through within the fourth parameter. In my case I concatenate the firstName and lastName variables and store them in profile.name but you can add anything you like in there.

Comment: I've just re-read the docs for onCreateUser and it looks like it will add the profile object to user without the additional code. The only reason I have it in my account.js file is because I use oAuth logins and have to tie multiple login services to one account. You should be fine if you use that event code without the server side accounts.js file.

Comment: Sorry, I'm slightly confused, does that mean I should keep my code as it is but just add any additional fields in the profiles that I want available?

Creating users is one thing I cannot get a grasp of in order to generate in most secure way.

Comment: Please see my edited code. The summary, newsInterest, otherstuff fields will not be populated until the user is created. But once they are signed in, these fields are immediately updated as the user types into text areas who's values are returned data from the respective profile fields.

Comment: Ah sorry okay. I'll update my answer with the additional code.

Comment: This helps, thank you. Please see a followup to what I am trying to do. Its a slight change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511187/meteor-insert-object-with-unique-id-upon-account-creation

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 is easily resolved using the [`Accounts.onCreateUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) callback on the server - it provides the user object to the callback, so you can just take the userId from this and insert a new "myProfile" with that owner.

As Will Parker points out below, the user document won't actually have an `_id` at this point though, so you need to create one and add it to the `user` object that the callback returns.  You can do this with:

```
user._id = Meteor.users._makeNewID();
```

Comment: Hi richsilv, actually when onCreateUser is called at that point the user hasn't been created yet so their is no id you can use as a foreign key. You could of course add the profile data for the user within the profile object on user. By altering the user.profile object before returning user.

Answer (score 0):

Q2: you have to send email, password and profile object to server and use the same `Accounts.createUser`. Everything works fine.