# Meteor: insert object with unique id upon account creation

Tags: meteor

Upon user account creation, I would like to insert the 'summary. and 'newsInterest' objects within the user profile that have a unique '_id' value and a 'text' field

```
summary: // _id: must have unique when account is created
            text: 
newsInterest: // id:
                 text:
```

This is so that I can use a session variable to update the 'text' values upon keyup depending on which input area the user is typing. So I need 'summary' and 'newsInterest' _id: immediately available after the user creates an account.

My account creation code is as follows.

```
Template.join.events({
'submit #join-form': function(e,t){
e.preventDefault();
  var firstName=  t.find('#join-firstName').value,
  lastName=  t.find('#join-lastName').value,
  email = t.find('#join-email').value,
  password = t.find('#join-password').value,
  username = firstName + '.' + lastName,
  profile = {
    name: firstName + ' ' + lastName
  };
  Accounts.createUser({
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    profile: profile
}, function(error) {
if (error) {
  alert(error);
} else {
  Router.go('home');
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: create random id using http://docs.meteor.com/#random and as like profile insert`summary` and `newsInterest` objects into profile in the same function

Comment: The random Id should be created on the server for security reasons. So how can I move the Accounts.createUser code onto the server?

Comment: Accounts.createUser is already available on both the client and the server and also there is the server only Accounts.onCreateUser

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the random ids? Are you planning on saving multiple versions of summary etc or is it just that you want it to have a kinda "primary key" because as the record is attached to the specific user you could just update based on their userId value.

Comment: Im not planning on saving multiple versions, but I am assuming the summary field amongst many others will be updates regularly by the user. Maybe there is a better way around what I'm trying to do. Imagine these fields displayed on a page. Anytime the user is on edit mode, I want these fields to be updated upon keyup event. I'm aiming for most efficient way of calling an update to a specific profile field instead of updating the entire profile object upon keyup.

Comment: I think this can only be achieved by giving each field a unique _id and setting the session _id depending on the 'focus' of the input, similarly to the way the latest todos example updates the todos list.

Comment: I don't think you need the id's particularly then. Think if you use the Meteor.userId variable as your unique identifier and then do an update like: Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId, {$set: {"profile.summary": newSummary}}); Syntax may be wrong but mongodb docs will have examples.

Comment: This way, I can write a keyup event for each input text area that is in 'focus'. This will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your client side createUser function as it is but attach the additional objects to profile on user creation on the server. This code should do it:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  profile = options.profile;
  profile.summary = {
    _id: Random.id(),
    content: ''
  };
  profile.newsInterest = {
    _id: Random.id(),
    content: ''
  };

  user.profile = profile;

  return user;
});
```

In order to use Random.id you will need to install the random package with: `meteor add random`

Comment: This code works in terms of creating the fields, I do have the random package installed but the _id fields are not being generated

Comment: try Random.id() instead sorry. That'll teach me to read the documentation properly.

Comment: I shall keep this for future reference, this code works by the way so thumbs up Will.